# My data is not getting posted to the server in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have added all the scripts required. The services are in asp.net, I have added as well the HTTP POST method in *web.config* file.

HTML form:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/InsertSession.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule1">
        <div ng-controller="mycontroller1">
            <form class="form-horizontal style-form" name="myform" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Event Title </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="title1">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Date of Event </label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="date" id="eventdate" name="eventdate" ng-model="eventdate">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Time of Event </label>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input class="form-control" type="time" id="eventtime" name="eventtime" ng-model="eventtime">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Event Location</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" class="form-control" ng-model="eventlocation1">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Event description</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" id="description" name=" description" class="form-control" ng-model="description1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" value="Create Event" ng-click="registereventdata()"> Submit </button>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!--ng-click="registereventdata()"   , ng-click="Insert(formdata)" ,type="submit"-->
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

AngularJS code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myModule1', []);
myapp.controller("mycontroller1", function ($scope, $http,$window) {


    $scope.registereventdata = function () {

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'WebService1.asmx/InsertSessionData',
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'datatype': 'json'
            },
            data: { Title: $scope.title1, Date: $scope.eventdate, Time: $scope.eventtime, Location: $scope.eventlocation1, Description: $scope.description1, CreatedDate: $scope.eventdate, Email: "xyz", IsActive: true, IsDelete: false }
        }).then(function (response) {
                if (response.data.d > 0) {
                    alert("event add successfully.");
                }
                else {
                    alert("opss!!!not register event..try again");
                }
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: In your navigator press F12 -> network tab. Check what happens, is a POST call being made ?

Comment: According to the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http you can pass a second function to your .then() to catch failures. If the request is failing out-right, you might have some information you're not exposing there.

Comment: As other mates have said, you must try to catch the error thrown, then, once you know what's happening, you may try to solve it yourself, or posting the information so others will be able to help you. Your Javascript code looks fine, so it's should be an issue on the server side or configuration.